# Direct Sum of Finite ring $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: combinatorics, direct-sum

Consider $R = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and some composite $k \in\mathbb{N}$. Clearly it forms a module over $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$.

I want to count maximal cardinality of a subset $B \subset R$ such that for every $b \in B$ there exists some $i \in\{1, 2, \ldots , k-1\}$ such that $i.r \not\in B$. I worked through some examples to possibly arrive at a pattern, but have not succeeded yet. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: It's 0. The result of scalar multiplication in a module always lies in the module. Or did you mean some special subset of $R$ instead?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thank you.. I just corrected my question. Apologize for the mistake.

Comment: Anything unclear?

Comment: @reuns yeah.. but everytime I added a comment to your answer.. somehow it got deleted. I agree with prime case (which helped me understand stuffs). But I don't understand the prime power case.

Comment: @reuns Could you possibly elaborate/explain? Especially, $B_{p^e}=(\Bbb{Z}/p^e \Bbb{Z})^n - (p^{e-1} \Bbb{F}_p{}^n - p^{e-1} B_p)$?

Comment: My reasoning is that for each $a\in (Z/p^e Z)^n-0$ there is some $p^k$ such that $p^k a\in (p^{e-1} Z/p^e Z)^n-0=p^{e-1} (F_p{}^n - 0)$ and removing exactly one element among $\{b p^k a,b\in 1\ldots p-1\}$ we get some subset satisfying your condition, which is maximal (ie. we can't add any element to it), and it is mostly obvious that it has the largest possible cardinality among subsets satisfying your condition.

Comment: Examples show that the orbits are not disjoint.. They intersect... So your argument for prime power case does not seem right..

Answer (score 0):

- If $k=p$ is prime then any largest subset $B_p$ will not contain $0$ and for each line $\in (\Bbb{F}_p{}^n -0)/\Bbb{F}_p^\times$ exactly one element will be removed, which means that $$|B_p| = p^n-1-\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$$
- If $k=p^e$ is a prime power then an optimal subset will be $$B_{p^e}=(\Bbb{Z}/p^e \Bbb{Z})^n - (p^{e-1} \Bbb{F}_p{}^n - p^{e-1} B_p), \qquad |B_{p^e}|=p^{en}-(1+\frac{p^n-1}{p-1})$$
- If $k=\prod_{j=1}^J p_j^{e_j}$ then I'm not sure. Maybe
  $$B_k=((\Bbb{Z}/p_j^{e_j} \Bbb{Z})^n-0)\oplus (\Bbb{Z}/\frac{k}{p_j^{e_j}} \Bbb{Z})^n$$ where $p_j^{e_j}$ is the largest prime power dividing $k$.